# HP Pavilion BIOS Failure. Unable to restore

Tags: laptop, bios, restore, firmware, hp-pavilion

My laptop BIOS seems to be dead. When I turn it on the CapsLock light blinks for 2 times and nothing happens on my screen. I tried to remove battery and power cable for some minutes, but nothing changed. I also removed the CMOS battery and replaced it's RAM, but still got the same problem.

I've searched for solutions on everywhere, and most of the times I finally get stuck on this page. The combination of WIN+B seems to have no effect, something that makes sense as I'm almost sure they've deleted the HP_TOOLS partition.

So, here is where I need your help. In the page mentioned above, it's said that "**a USB key with an HP_TOOLS volume can be used as an alternative**". I really have searched everywhere, but I can't find how to create this USB drive. I also have no idea where to find an **extracted version of BIOS** so I could restore from that. The only BIOS That I get from the driver's page is one ".exe" which I have to run it on that computer, which is impossible.

*As a user in HP forums suggested, I've downloaded the latest HP PC Hardware Diagnostics and installed them in a USB Drive. The result was the same as before, nothing happened. In the USB was created a subfolder named BIOS, including 3 other subfolders named "Curent, New, Previous" Which all of them are empty.*

**So, to sum up, I need:**

1. BIOS recovery files
2. a way to create a working USB drive with HP_TOOLS
3. any other idea or suggestion would be very welcome

**Tried, but didn't work:**

- restart
- remove HDD
- remove CMOS battery
- replace RAMs
- WIN+B combination
- WIN+B combination, with the flash drive mentioned above connected
- **The laptop is:** HP Pavilion DV6-2117ev (drivers page is [here](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/softwareCategory?os=4063&lc=en&cc=gr&dlc=el&sw_lang=&product=4123830))
- **Serial number:** CNF9525GV4
- **Product number:** WB331EA#B1A
- **Operating system:** Probably Windows 7 (I don't think this has any importance right now)

Comment: Replace the motherboard.

Comment: Did you check this post out on HP support: http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Lockups-Freezes-Hangs/Fixing-A-laptop-which-had-had-a-bad-BIOS-upgrade/td-p/225042

Comment: @CameronVerotti thanks for your suggestion, I'll try out this method too and I'll inform you if it has worked.

Comment: @CameronVerotti Unfortunately that does not work either. Seems like the BIOS has to be replaced, and can't be done from the computer itself. Thanks for your help tho, I appreciate it!

Comment: No problem, good luck!

Comment: I have the **same exact** problem, with a dv5-1140ep. I guess I really can declare it dead and gone.