# Program to format external drive to FAT16 in Windows 8.1

Tags: windows, usb, format, fat16

As the title says, I need a program to format my USB as FAT16. The default windows format option has only FAT, FAT32 and NTFS options. I'm using Windows 8.1

Thanks in advance.

Comment: ( its not offered because Windows 8.1 does not support that filesystem neither does Windows 7 )

Comment: hmm well I have to flash a BIOS on a laptop I have, and some people suggested me that FAT16 is the best file system for that, as It has to be recognised as a diskette. So the only way to do it is probably from a Linux enviroment?

Comment: Have you tried just using FAT32?

Comment: Yeah, and FAT too, and everything. So this is my last chance to check if it can be fixed or not..

Comment: Without more information I can't respond.  If a FAT32 drive didn't work I can guarantee you a FAT16 drive won't work.

Comment: If you like to check out for what laptops I'm referring, you can check out [this](http://superuser.com/questions/838246/hp-pavilion-bios-failure-unable-to-restore) and [this](http://superuser.com/questions/839111/aspire-5820t-post-error) topic that I've created before. And yes, FAT32, FAT and even NTFS didn't work for either of them. But anyway, thanks for your time!

Comment: Your problem isn't the filesystem your problem is the laptops are dead and are not even attempting to POST.  For you to even be able to update the BIOS the devices have to POST.

Comment: The computer is not able to POST if the BIOS is not working. I know that probably the laptops are dead, but before throwing away 1k+ euros devices, I first have to try every possible solution.

Comment: To my knowledge POST isn't even a function of the BIOS.....

Comment: I'm almost sure it is.. At least that's what I understood by reading [this](http://helpdesk.oneonta.edu/resnet/training/bios.htm#post) and the main [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power-on_self-test).. Anyway, as we talk I formated the USB to FAT16 on Ubuntu VM, and this is not working either.. So I think the lives of those laptops have officially ended tonight.

Answer (score 1):

In the Windows Format dialog, FAT refers to FAT16. If you choose FAT, it will format with FAT16.

Comment: Hello and thanks for your reply. Are you really sure about this? I've seen this answer in many forums, but based on Wikipedia, the FAT file system has the following versions: Original 8-bit FAT, FAT12, Initial FAT16, Logical sectored FAT, Final FAT16, FAT32. And that's the reason I'm trying to find a most accurate answer on this community.

Comment: Final FAT16 was the first to allow a disk size greater than 32MB. You can try choosing "FAT" in the Windows Format dialog and you'll see that you are able to create a volume greater than 32MB, therefore, it must be FAT16.

Comment: @ChrisKaridis the type of FAT is determined by the number of clusters it has, not by name. FAT12 volumes can only address at most 4078 clusters (may vary on some special system), FAT16 partitions **must** have from 4079 to 65524 clusters. Any partions that have more than 65524 must be FAT32. They can all be addressed as FAT. FAT12's maximum partition size is 32MB. Any partition larger than 32MB must be FAT16/32. For FAT 8-bit even DOS doesn't support it.